# Custom Installer : Detect Ajax Framework

Tags: ajax, installation

i am building a custom installer for a site, and am wanting to find out, how do i detect for certain system requirements, ie my site uses ajax, so how do i check if ajax is installed, if not install it?

Can i do the same for sql express?

An idea that would also be great is to maybe as the user if they would like to install the extra features with a message box. ie; if ajax is not installed, it prompts the user if they would like to install the ajax framework.

thanks in advance
chris

Answer (score 0):

I get the  impression your question is not adequately labeled. Ajax is an extremely general term - you seem to imply you want to check for a particular ajax framework. (Asp.NET AJAX?)

By the looks of to you are in fact talking about windows server platform. If that is the case, can't you query the windows registry?

Comment: yes sorry, i realised my error, and have labled the question correctly. yes basically from the installer io have created a custom installer class that will check if the ajax framework is installed. if it is not installed i need to install it or throw and error to the user. would checking the registry be the best option?

Comment: I don't know if that's the best solution. I'm not a .NET developer.